# Very basic question: Is my postgres password set correctly? When are we using postgres passwords?

Tags: postgresql

```html
[LuisMontanoMichel@Luis-MacBook-Pro~% psql
psql (14.2)
Type
"help" for help.
[LuisMontanoMichel=# ALTER ROLE
"LuisMontanoMichel" WITH PASSWORD 'examplepass':
ALTER ROLE
[LuisMontanoMichel=# \q
[LuisMontanoMichel@Luis-MacBook-Pro~% psql
psql
(14.2)
Type
"help"
for help.
LuisMontanoMichel=#
```

I have a very basic question about postgres passwords.
I set my own but I still can start psql without typing it.
When will my password be used?

Comment: This is likely because you have `ident` authentication method in your `pg_hba.conf` file. Try changing that to `password` (and restart postgres of course).

Comment: Password usage is controlled by pg_hba.conf file, so look in there.  (But don't change it to `password`, use at least `md5`.)